# Is it possible for Selenium C# test to pick up a parameter from a batch or powershell script?

Tags: c#, powershell, selenium, batch-file, arguments

I have Selenium tests which navigate to a URL: `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.blahwhatever.com");`

I can now run Selenium tests using a batch file or PowerShell script, which will, hopefully, be picked up and run by Octopus Deploy when a new build is deployed.

We want one PowerShell or batch script per environment and need the test code to be passed the environment URL from the batch file e.g

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url passed from batch file);
```

I can't see how to do this. Perhaps this is not possible?
I know how to pick up the URL from an excel spreadsheet but my colleagues do not want to do it this way.

Comment: In Java it is surely possible to read commandline output. Thats a trail I would follow. So let your batchfile echo the url you need and pick it up with C# if possible. Or I might have misunderstood something which is likely possible :D

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I will follow that up

Comment: you can always write the URL from the batch to a logfile (txt), then streamreader that file in and gotoURL it that way

Comment: Thank you for you response.  I will definitely look into that.

Comment: I solved this by using an excel file with the various environment urls in a dropdown list in the first cell.  I put code in the tests to take the environment url from that cell.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.

The easiest way I see is to use environment variables.

Powershell can set environment variable:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("testurl",$null,"User")
```

C# code can read environment variable:

```
var url = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("testurl");
```

P.S. As an opinion, you can do it much easier by reading url from App.config, and use Octopus's built in configuration transformations to accomplish per-environment scoping.